# Transparency Error when using table in parfor loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parfor

I am trying to use a table within a parfor loop in MATLAB. This gives me "Transparency violation error. See Parallel Computing Toolbox about transparency"  I'm trying to build this table so I can make a prediction using a trained classifier from the MATLAB classification learner app (`trainedClassifier.prefictFcn(T)`)...so either I need to build a table within the `parfor` loop or need some alternative to a table that I can still feed into the classifier.

```
parfor i=1:100
    acheck=1;
    bcheck=2;
    ccheck=3;
    T=table(acheck,bcheck,ccheck);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for your particular problem:

```
parfor i=1:100
    acheck=1;
    bcheck=2;
    ccheck=3;
    T(i,:)=table([acheck,bcheck,ccheck]);
end
```

Note that in your original program you just overwrite existing values and end up with a one row table. I assumed that that was not intended. Actually, that would be the outcome of a for.

Also, since this is a parfor and T is created inside the loop (as well as acheck, etc.) using just T creates nothing at all. The variable is a temporary one, visible to each process locally and destroyed in global scope (more can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/transparency.html)).

To fix both overwriting and accessibility the program assigns the each set of variables to each row of T. If square brackets are omitted, the program throws a transparency error. Unfortunately, I do not know why is that but it may be that the operations done by the table data-structure cause that. Maybe someone else will know the answer, for now this seem to solve your problem though.